# AudioKit multiple AKMIDISampler

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I wanted to know if it was possible for AudioKit to have multiple outputs, for instance two AKMIDISampler's. At the moment it seems like it can only have one.

I would assume this would be possible if I use an AKMixer, so if someone recommends that I use that I have one question. I'm using a soundfont ".sf2" file to initalize the AKMIDISampler, if I have multiple AKMIDISampler's using different soundfont files where both have the same MIDINoteNumber's but different audio results, how would I be able to differentiate from one sampler to the other?

Any pointers and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable request for AudioKit to be able fulfill.  The thing is its not a great StackOverflow question because there's not just one clear answer. What I would suggest that you and anyone else that would like AudioKit to "x" would be to set up a project that you think should work ideally, even if it doesn't, and then share it publicly so the AudioKit core team can easily download it and try it out.

Comment: Okay, I'll create a small project and upload it to Github soon. Once I've done that I'll write to you again. Thanks.